# How to draw a tree with the id as the node labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

If I make a tree using networkx, by default the nodes have integer ids. I would like to visualise the tree with the integers labelling the nodes. So instead of:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
T = nx.generators.balanced_tree(2, 2)
nx.draw(T)
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I write the integer labels inside the nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `nx.draw`, use `nx.draw_networkx`. It has a keyword argument `with_labels` that is True by default, so you don't really have to change anything except the function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
T = nx.generators.balanced_tree(2, 2)
nx.draw_networkx(T)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Or just `nx.draw(with_labels=True)` which is arguably cleaner as it doesn't also change other defaults.